# Explain why $E[XY\mid X]=XE[Y\mid X]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I'm getting through the logic of $E[XY\mid X]=X(E[Y\mid X])$: since $E[X\mid X]=X$ is a constant, so we can pull the term $X$ out, and we get $X(E[Y\mid X])$. Is this the right way to think about this proposition?

Comment: What's your definition of $E[XY|X]$ ? I would argue that $X$ is $\sigma(X)$-mesurable and use a well-known property of conditional expectation.

Comment: Another view which is useful particularly when $X$ is discrete is $$E[XY|X=x] = E[xY|X=x] = xE[Y|X=x]$$ for all $x$ in the set of values $X$ can take.

Comment: $X$ is not really a constant.  Better to think of $E[XY|X=x] = xE[Y|X=x]$ as a function of $x$, and thus $E[XY|X]$ and $XE[Y|X]$ as functions of a random variable which must therefore be equal to each other

Comment: One wonders if it is humanly possible to get people to learn to type $\operatorname{E}(Y\mid X)$ instead of $\operatorname{E}(Y|X). \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy A question that will betray my ignorance: why is the left one preferred? It doesn't look much better to me, but maybe I just have bad taste. Is there another reason?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery : Legibility, when the expressions before and after that symbol are more involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a generalization of linearity. For conventional expectation, we have $E(XY)=XE(Y)$ when $X$ is a constant. Conventional expectation can be thought of as expectation with respect to the trivial sigma algebra, and a function is measurable w.r.t. the trivial sigma algebra iff it's constant. The general version is that $E(XY\mid F)=XE(Y\mid F)$ iff $X$ is $F$-measurable, where $F$ is some sigma algebra.

Intuitively, for $X$ to be $F$ measurable means that you "know" the value of $X$ given the information $F$, and $E(Z\mid F)$ is the "best guess" as to the value of $Z$ given the information $F$, so obviously if you know $X$ then your best guess for $XY$ is going to be $X$ times your best guess for $Y$.

Comment: "The general version is that $E(XY|F)=XE(Y|F)$ iff $X$ is $F$-measurable" Actually, **if** would be correct but **iff** is not true.

Comment: @Did Why isn't *iff* true?

Comment: @Did I'm so used to typing iff I didn't even realize. I suppose there's no reason you couldn't come up with some non $F$-measurable function for which the property just so happens to work.

Comment: Because there are (simple) cases when E(XY|F)=XE(Y|F) and yet X is not F-measurable (as, I guess, Jack will soon explain).

Comment: @learning Well, $Y=0$ for one.

Comment: Haha, of course I miss such a trivial example!

Comment: @JackM Do you have any other examples? I can't think of any.

Answer (score -4):

When you write $\operatorname{E}(\cdot\mid X),$ then within that narrow context you're treating the value of $X$ as given, thus "constant" and not "random".