# Step in deriving the expectation of the product of a binomial and a uniform distribution involving the gamma function.

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-function

I'm trying to follow [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4075529/152225), and got stuck in the use of the gamma function in the third step:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[XY]
&= \sum_{y=0}^n \int_{x=0}^1 xy \binom{n}{y} x^y (1-x)^{n-y} \, dx \\
&= \sum_{y=0}^n y \binom{n}{y} \int_{x=0}^1 x^{y+1} (1-x)^{n-y} \, dx \\
&= \sum_{y=0}^n y \binom{n}{y} \frac{\Gamma(y+2)\Gamma(n-y+1)}{\Gamma(n+3)} \\
\end{align}

My guess is that this is a well-known method to eliminate the integral, and then greatly simplify things by considering that $y$ is a natural number.

The equation, though, is rather intimidating. I see for instance that $\Gamma(y+2) =\int_0^\infty x^{(y+1)}e^{-x}dx,$ which is promising, but there is that pesky exponential, plus the limits of integration are different, let alone the fact that there are now three integrals at play.

Comment: Look up the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: @angryavian So this is saying that $\int_0^1 x^{y+1}(1-x)^{n-y}dx=\int_0^1 f_{(X=x; \alpha,\beta)} \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)},$ where $\alpha =y+2$ and $\beta = n-y+1.$ And now $\int_0^1 f_{(X=x; \alpha,\beta)} =1, $and the fraction with gamma functions is simply a number.